# Access response body after multiple res.write()s

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

How do I access the response body after doing multiple res.write()s? Simplified example:

```
endpoint(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  res.write('{"resdata":')
  //Stream data, format it, and then add to the response
  res.write(stream1)
  res.write(', "resdata2":')
  
  //Stream some other data, format it, and then add to the response:
  res.write(stream2)
  res.write('}')

  var savedBody = res.getBody() //Is there a way to extract the response body here from all the res.writes()?
  res.end()

  doSomethingElseWithResponseBody(savedBody)
}
```

Technically, I could create my own JSON and then do a single res.send at the end -- I know -- but in the specific implementation of this, it's very difficult to use that method; the res.writes() need to be kept.

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: No.  There's no way to get the accumulated data from a stream, some of which may already be sent.  If you want to know what was sent, then accumulate it yourself as you go.  You can make a helper function that accumulates it for you and calls `res.write()` or, as you said, you can accumulate it yourself and then send it all at once at the  end (if the data is not large).

Comment: You could also hack the `res` stream (by overriding `.write()` or other methods) and accumulate the data that way though I wouldn't recommend that because it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: @jfriend00 A slightly related question.. if the code does res.write() multiple times, and then at the end it does res.send(json), will the json override the other things written before it as its sent?

Comment: `res.write()` and `res.json()` are not meant to be compatible.  Use one or more `res.write()` followed by `res.end()` OR use `res.json()` - not both.  I don't know exactly what will happen if you try your scenario, but you should not write your code that way.  At best, it will just fail to set some of the headers that `res.json()` would normally  try to set - at worst, it will throw.  If you absolutely must know what happens, run an experiment and try it.  But, mixing them is not a correct way to code.

Comment: FYI, `res.json()` will not override prior `res.write()`.  Internally, `res.json()` is also using `res.write()` so best case is it will just add more content to the stream.  Worst case, it will see that you've already flushed headers and will trigger an error because `res.json()` can't set the content-type it wants to set.

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it, appreciate the explanation of how they work. Will likely just try to accumulate it into a JSON if possible

Comment: I would create a separate object that proxies the res object, and also does whatever else you want it to do.